# What information transferred in Zoom recorded?

Tags: zoom.us

I was wondering how Zoom is with regards to privacy.

When I share my facecam, is my information saved on a Zoom server somewhere to assist with facial recognition? If I share my screen, does Facebook observe and record what is shown? Can Facebook or Zoom observe data sent inside of Zoom calls, regardless of whether the session is recorded?